# Rewriting URL with 3 custom meta fields to add onto Pages

Tags: url-rewriting

Have been struggling with this for some time, simply out of my depth here...

- I made a Custom Post Type 'hotels'.
- My site is based on pages and structured thus: home/country/region/city/

I now want to add hotels/hotel-name to the end of that url structure, and have the breadcrumbs reflect that structure - meaning, users would be able to click on 'region' or 'city' and be directed to the right page. Not sure if that is at all possible.

home/country/region/city/hotels/hotel-name

Since there are no taxonomies involved, only Pages, I thought about using 3 custom meta fields on the hotel page: country, region and city, and then rewriting the url.

I guess this would work for the url, but would the breadcrumbs work as hoped?

If so, I found this code snippet that seems to do what I want, but I don't know how to add the 2 other meta fields to it.

```
function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%city%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^city/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?city=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help. I hope I am making sense!

Comment: and those country, region, city links surely clickable at your breadcrumbs, right? does these links also have separate pages?

Comment: Yes, exactly, they have pages and are clickable,